# How to parse asString() unirest response

Tags: java, unirest

I have a unirest response that I need to parse and it returns a string response. Kindly check the code below:

```
HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("http://api.nuvelco.com/token")
                     .header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                     .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
                     .body("grant_type=password&username=" + uname + "&password=" + pword + "&client_id=paymentApp")
                     .asString();
```

I am unaware how to parse a `asString()` request so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I forgot to include the response

```
{
    "access_token":"HzDzAtlom6CDqRa0zPetH09hZbDr8tm__hPw7aCx2m0h0gnGwHMaKvBEp64sHRUCJJEAlhCNUqQ3tBSyvod_93gTnt145W2ly9KKw5ISmaZRN75O9NUfJUGPRd0LH87LlxiRgHNFkUGTUDwyJOmhYNajj7TQoncxqkfc3jxL-jEi3Ea1cGRvOSmLH5Aqom81kKmiRzPV_Ss0xwFWjQVsS03y_P720Hv1BQEayO9L7Vic4A64GmXm3PlFQuwcvOk3M_7WOa_EEGOFBZdhwn7dzNQ7gypJ27MSTOD3gI57880unF4XFgTT_H4p4G5V6C8L8yRbRNXPIe80gLKYk3F3nw",
    "token_type":"bearer",
    "expires_in":3599,
    "refresh_token":"f87a5fea7d764826be24bd742626d0d8",
    "as:client_id":"paymentApp",
    "username":"savemore01",
    ".issued":"Wed, 05 Dec 2018 03:13:23 GMT",
    ".expires":"Wed, 05 Dec 2018 04:13:23 GMT"
}
```

Comment: What is sent by the server?

Comment: Please check edits

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json-simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/) a simple Java library for JSON. So you can parse the string response value to something like that :

```
HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = Unirest.post("http://api.nuvelco.com/token")
                     .header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                     .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
                     .body("grant_type=password&username=" + uname + "&password=" + pword + "&client_id=paymentApp")
                     .asString();

String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

Object object = JSONValue.parse(response);
```

Note that the package of EntityUtils is **org.apache.http.util**

Comment: The `genEntity()` method is returning an error on my side and it requires a casting to an `request.body.Body`. I tried that casting but it returned an error that it can't be casted